# What kind of non-chord tone dissonance is this?

Tags: theory, terminology, ornaments

[image: score excerpt, bass staff, mm. 84-86]

What is the correct term for this type of non-chord tone? I really like the sound of it and since I see it a lot I was wondering if an "official" name exists for it. It is not a suspension because the P4th does not resolve over the next chord (Eb) at the beginning of the second bar. Instead, a second dissonance is created (M2) before resolving to a M3 on the upbeat.

Comment: It's not really a suspension because the F is non-chordal, but it behaves like one: resolving to the fifth of the C-minor 1st inversion chord.

Comment: The treble upper stave(s) should be included here. Whatever is happening there could impact the answer by changing the OP-given analysis of C minor followed by Eb major.

Comment: @Aaron, there is nothing there. It is just the two voices. THanks for checking

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, it's a **passing tone**, but with a delayed resolution. There's no "official" music theory term for this.

Comment: there are 2 intervals created one after the other so how can it be a passing tone? isnt that only against one other stationary note?

Comment: @armani A passing tone is any non-chord tone that serves to connect two chord tones. It doesn't matter that the harmony happens to change.

Comment: @armani Consider also that since this is a two-voice texture, the second bar doesn't necessarily start with Eb major — it could be C minor in second inversion.

Comment: ok, and f it were Cmin in second inversion, how does that change anything? doesnt it not matter since the dissonance is still a P4 and M2 against the bass notes

Comment: also, dont you mean 1st inversion? C/Eb

Comment: @armani Yes, first inversion. The intervals don't matter. What matters is that the F is leading from a chord tone to another chord tone. The arrival just happens to be delayed.

Comment: I really like this interpretation. Although the texturing gives the appearance of a suspension-like dissonance, if you look closely this is indeed a passing tone happening inside of a C minor harmony.

Comment: Thanks, @Ootagu. I agree — it really does "feel" suspended; calling it a "passing tone", while technically correct, doesn't really capture the feel.

Answer (score 1):

the harmony in this bar is Eb (respective to your earlier posting)

the note F is an *appoggiatura* resolving to the 3rd (G) - in common practice it was on the beat but - in pop and jazz it is ahead of  the beat:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appoggiatura

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we could call it an anticipated suspension?

Comment: Nice! You are thinking outside the box :)

Answer (score 0):

The first F occuring against the C bass can also be seen as a chord tone! The F against the C implies F-minor. Although this creates a fourth with the bass C and and is often defined as a dissonance in strict counterpoint, in strict harmony it is a chord change as opposed to a dissonance. After the barline it then becomes a dissonance against the E-flat and could be called a retardation resolving upwards to the G. (On a side note the harmony after the barline is also ambiguous; it can taken as carrying on the C minor previous)

Comment: THanks for your analysis. What did you mean by "strict harmony"?

Comment: I admit it was a strange term which I made up myself. I was trying to emphasize a purely harmonic mode of thinking because I know oftentimes we can get caught in the idea that a fourth is always dissonant.